# Can't get sabisu gem to render - shows no input found for inet error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

so i'm working through the api on rails tutorial - http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book - and i keep getting the error 'no input found for inet' in my error window.

the error highlights this block of code as where the issue is occuring:

```
<div class="appeareable">
    <% @explorer.resource_columns.each do |column| %>
        <%= f.input column, input_html: {name: "#{@explorer.resource_name}[#{column}]" }, as: @explorer.column_type(column), required: @explorer.required_attribute?(column) %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I tried locking out the compass and simple_form gems, but there are dependencies that start to fall apart using rails 4.1.4 and ruby 2.1.5.

it looks like simple_form is trying to render a resource named 'inet', but i can't find that anywhere in the gem code or even referenced anywhere on google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that simple_form has a problem handling the 'inet' datatype now included in rails 4 by default for postgres - https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/new-in-rails-4 (ctrl-f for inet).

IPs used to be string datatype (varchar 255 in postgres) and so converting the db to string for the 2 IP fields in the user table (current_sign_in_ip and last_sign_in_ip) resolves this issue.

I would imagine simple_form will be updating to handle this new datatype at somepoint...though I didn't see any mention of it in their issue logs.

I did this by adding a new migration:

```
rails g migration change_ip_columns_in_users_table
```

Then I edited the migration file:

```
class ChangeIpColumnsInUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :string
        change_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :string
    end
end
```

Answer (score -2):

The migration solved the problem.